# Camera preview takePicture function not working Ionic?

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I am trying to get the takePicture function to work and get the imageData, but no luck so far. I have tried the new Beta plugin Camera Preview, but that will not start the camera at all.

I have the plugin com.mbppower.camerapreview and npm install --save @ionic-native/camera-preview.

I just need to get the imageData from the takePicture, but don't know how?

This is the code:

```
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, ToastController } from 'ionic-angular';


import firebase from 'firebase';
import { CameraPreview, CameraPreviewRect } from 'ionic-native';
import { Diagnostic } from 'ionic-native';
import { File } from 'ionic-native';


import { AlertProvider } from '../../providers/alertprovider';
import { ImageProvider } from '../../providers/imageprovider';

declare var cordova: any; // global variable for paths
 @Component({
  selector: 'page-upload',
  templateUrl: 'upload.html'
})

export class UploadPage {
  public user: any;

  constructor(private nav: NavController, private zone:NgZone, private 
  cameraPreview: CameraPreview, public diagnostic: Diagnostic, public 
  toastCtrl: ToastController,
  public imageProvider: ImageProvider, public alertProvider: AlertProvider){

}

ionViewDidEnter(){

    this.checkPermissions();
}

ionViewWillLeave() {

    CameraPreview.stopCamera();
}

checkPermissions() {

    Diagnostic.isCameraAuthorized().then((authorized) => {
        if(authorized)
            this.initializePreview();
        else {
            Diagnostic.requestCameraAuthorization().then((status) => {
                if(status == Diagnostic.permissionStatus.GRANTED)
                    this.initializePreview();
                else {
                    // Permissions not granted
                    // Therefore, create and present toast
                    this.toastCtrl.create(
                        {
                            message: "Cannot access camera", 
                            position: "bottom",
                            duration: 5000
                        }
                    ).present();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}   

initializePreview() {
    // Make the width and height of the preview equal 
    // to the width and height of the app's window
    let previewRect: CameraPreviewRect = {
    x: 0,
    y: 57,
    width: window.innerWidth,
    height: window.innerHeight/2
    };

    // More code goes here
    // Start preview
    CameraPreview.startCamera(
        previewRect, 
        'rear', 
        true, 
        true, 
        false,
        1
    );

    CameraPreview.setOnPictureTakenHandler().subscribe((imageData) => {
        // Process the returned imageURI.
        let imgBlob = this.imageProvider.imgURItoBlob("data:image/jpeg;base64," + imageData);
        let metadata = {
            'contentType': imgBlob.type
        };

        firebase.storage().ref().child('images/' + this.user.userId + '/cards' + '/' + this.imageProvider.generateFilename()).put(imgBlob, metadata).then((snapshot) => {
            // URL of the uploaded image!
            let url = snapshot.metadata.downloadURLs[0];

        }).catch((error) => {
            this.alertProvider.showErrorMessage('image/error-image-upload');
        });


    });
}

takePicture() {

    CameraPreview.takePicture({maxWidth: 1280, maxHeight: 1280});

}


}
```

Cordova CLI: 6.5.0

Ionic Framework Version: 3.0.1

Ionic CLI Version: 2.2.3

Ionic App Lib Version: 2.2.1

Ionic App Scripts Version: 1.3.0

ios-deploy version: Not installed

ios-sim version: Not installed

OS: Windows 10

Node Version: v6.10.0

Xcode version: Not installed

Comment: Have you checked the logs ?

Comment: No, the problem is if I write the following code I get an error: CameraPreview.takePicture(function(base64PictureData){
  /* code here */
});

Comment: Which error do you get ?

Comment: if you are using ionic-native 3 you need to use the objects you inject and not the class http://ionicframework.com/docs/native/

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? I am new to Ionic and have tried everything.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 // More code goes here
// Start preview
CameraPreview.startCamera(
    previewRect, 
    'rear', 
    true, 
    true, 
    false,
    1
)
```

use this make toBack false it will bring camera preview to the front.

```
 // More code goes here
// Start preview
CameraPreview.startCamera(
    previewRect, 
    'rear', 
    false, 
    true, 
    false,
    1
)
```

if that does not solve your problem remove that camera plugin and use this latest one

```
ionic plugin add https://github.com/cordova-plugin-camera-preview/cordova-plugin-camera-preview.git
```

this has new fixes which are not available on npm yet.